# unsupported grant_type?

Tags: rest-api

When I'm executing a web service on "**Advanced REST client (a chrome extension)"**, I'm getting this error constantly. I do need to get "**access_token**"

```
{
    error_description: "grant type not supported"
    error: "unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

And I'm passing my username, password (password+Security token), client_id, client_secret and grant_type(=password).

The url is https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Comment: The service you are calling is to get the oauth token. You'd then use that token with your call to your webservice illustrated in this answer http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22704/sessionid-problem-in-schedule-batch-class/23206#23206

Answer (score 7):

The `content-type` HTTP header should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - Check if that's set correctly. If not, you will get this error. Also, make sure The `grant_type` form parameter is set to your password (all lower case)