# Making apex callout after sendEmail() in Batch apex

Tags: email, batch, future, schedule

This is related to question, [Processing callouts from Batch](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24935/processing-callouts-from-batch), but is specific to Emails operations. 
We are sending contents of email in apex callouts. The content contain merge fields, which is not populated unless emails are sent. 
So, we can't make callout before emails are sent. The question is how to make the callouts now??

Not possible:

1. Email services can't be used as there will be a lot of emails.
2. Another future method can't be used.

I need help in knowing, What could be the possible & Optimal approach to resolve the issue??
Can we process the contents of emails jst sent in Salesforce or Do we need to store this information in custom object/Custom settings??

Thanks for your help guys...:)