# System.LimitException: Too many future calls: 1 in batch finish

Tags: apex, batch, future

I have actually a batch on user, where user are activated or deactivated based on a criteria. In each execute I update my set of users, which in turn launch an @future method to recalculate the role for each user. The method need to be @future and is executed on trigger for user after update. The problem is that this generate the following error :

```
 System.AsyncException: Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method:
```

I understood that as each execute is considered as a future call, I cannot execute another future from my trigger in each batch execute. So i decided to update all my users in my finish, which will call my future method, but now I am obtaining the following error :

```
System.LimitException: Too many future calls: 1
```

Does this mean that will not be able to execute a future method from a batch ??? If not, then how can I achieve this?

This is  not a duplicate of [Calling future method from batch class?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57154/calling-future-method-from-batch-class), because there it is doing callouts whereas in my case, I am recuring to @future because in a user trigger i cannot do any other DML. Also their hasn't been any best answer marked there.

Comment: You can go for batch class chaining by starting another batch from finish method, which will handle the same logic that you want in the future method.

Comment: @RohitMourya, can you place your comment as answer instead, such that if it works , i can mark it as best answer. Because I actually implemented your suggestion on my sandbox and it is working. I will now deploy it to my prod where i was getting the issues.

Comment: @vanessen done. I'm glad that my suggestion solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement **Queueable** class which acts as a `Future` method and then you can invoke other `future` method. This is indirect way of calling future method from future method (A `queueable` class method acts as a future method). But this approach also has **governor limit of 2**. So at max you can call two future methods.