# Alternative of Batch calling Future method

Tags: trigger, batch, callout, future

I've looked around to try to find some posts on this and there are many but none that address my specific question (that I could find).

I am trying to call a @Future method inside a **for loop** in my trigger class from Batch. I tried Queueable/WebService and I don't know why but I am not getting expected result.

**1st issue**:  I have a method let say **FutureMethod** which is a @Future method and we can't call @Future from a batch.

**2nd issue**:  The **FutureMethod** does a callout, so the method must be @Future as callouts from triggers are not allowed.

Please suggest me the way or Alternate way to solve this problem.

Comment: use [Queuable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) apex.

Comment: Personally I think you have 3 issues. The first is calling a @future method from a loop in general. You are bound to encounter 1 or more platform limits using such a design. From what I can tell, Queuable is the apex feature you should work towards, see Dan Applemans [video](https://www.salesforce.com/video/192729/). You could also review some answers on [Calling future method from Batch](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24843/calling-future-method-from-batch)

Comment: You can't call multiple Queueables from a batch either. You need to either set your batch size to one or find a way to bulkify the endpoint you are calling, in addition to any move to Queueable. Please note, however, that you *can* call out synchronously from a batch.