# Batch Class calling Future Method Error

Tags: callout, scheduled-apex

I have below scheduelable class but issue is after executing this it is triggering another class and calling future method.. i need my that future to be called but needs to avoid that error. (one possible solution is make that future method queable). But not sure how to do that.. I am posting my code for batch and future method both. Please provide me the solution

Schedulable Class:

```java
public with sharing class BatchToUpdateIPiSeq extends ilib_ScheduleAndBatch implements Schedulable{
       
     /*
     * Default constructor
     */ 
    public BatchToUpdateIPiSeq(){
        
    }
   
    
    /*
*  Description: Execute method to be called when class is scheduled
**/
    public override void execute(SchedulableContext ctx)
    {
        BatchToUpdateIPiSeq objBatch=new BatchToUpdateIPiSeq();
        Database.executebatch(objBatch);
    }
    /*
* Description: Fetch required installed products to process
*/
    public override Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        string strQuery;
        Set<String> productCode = new Set<String>{'20021532','20040619'};
        strQuery = 'Select Id, Name, SVMXC__Company__r.IsPartner, Operation_Status__c, SVMXC__Status__c, Acceptance_Date__c, SVMXC__Date_Installed__c, SVMXC__Date_Shipped__c FROM SVMXC__Installed_Product__c WHERE Product_Code__c IN:productCode AND SVMXC__Status__c = \'Shipped\' AND Operation_Status__c = NULL AND Acceptance_Date__c = NULL AND SVMXC__Date_Installed__c = NULL';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(strQuery);
    }
      /*
* Process the qualified records as batchs
*/
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SVMXC__Installed_Product__c> records){
            for(SVMXC__Installed_Product__c objIP : records){
                Date startDate = objIP.SVMXC__Date_Shipped__c;
                Date dueDate = Date.Today();
                Integer numberDaysDue = startDate.daysBetween(dueDate);

                if(numberDaysDue>90 && !objIP.SVMXC__Company__r.IsPartner){
                    objIP.Operation_Status__c = 'On';
                    objIP.SVMXC__Status__c = 'Installed';
                    objIP.Acceptance_Date__c = system.today();
                    objIP.SVMXC__Date_Installed__c = system.today();
                     
                }
                 if(numberDaysDue>120 && objIP.SVMXC__Company__r.IsPartner){
                    objIP.Operation_Status__c = 'On';
                    objIP.SVMXC__Status__c = 'Installed';
                    objIP.Acceptance_Date__c = system.today();
                    objIP.SVMXC__Date_Installed__c = system.today();
                     
                }
                if(records.size()>0)    
                update records;
        
           }
    }
    public override void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        system.debug('inside finish method.');
    }
}
```

After executing this it is calling below method (in AfterUpdate trigger) and causing an error:

```
if (setInstalledProductIds.size() > 0)
            sendInstalledProductToSAP(setInstalledProductIds);

@future(callout = true)
    public static void sendInstalledProductToSAP(Set<Id> setInstalledProductIds)
    {
        if (setInstalledProductIds == null || setInstalledProductIds.size() == 0) return;
        System.debug('== I am in future method');

        for (SVMXC__Installed_Product__c instProd : new InstalledProductsSelector().selectInstalledProductsFromIds(setInstalledProductIds))
        {
            if (instProd.ERP_Equipment_Id__c == null || instProd.SVMXC__Company__r.ERP_Customer_Id__c == null)
                setInstalledProductIds.remove(instProd.Id);
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you see the answer to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24843/calling-future-method-from-batch?

Comment: Hi @PrashanthK, I have seen that but not sure how to implement that. Can you advise in terms of code mentioned above,

Answer (score 0):

Queueable apex can be called from Batch. I have given below the implementation for the same.

```
if (setInstalledProductIds.size() > 0)
    ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(new sendInstalledProductToSAP(setInstalledProductIds));
```

Migrating the future to Queueable Apex:

```
public class sendInstalledProductToSAP implements Queueable,Database.AllowsCallouts {
    public Set<Id> setInstalledProductIds
    public sendInstalledProductToSAP(Set<Id> setInstalledProductIds){
        this.setInstalledProductIds = setInstalledProductIds;
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        if (setInstalledProductIds == null || setInstalledProductIds.size() == 0) return;

        for (SVMXC__Installed_Product__c instProd : new InstalledProductsSelector().selectInstalledProductsFromIds(setInstalledProductIds))
        {
            if (instProd.ERP_Equipment_Id__c == null || instProd.SVMXC__Company__r.ERP_Customer_Id__c == null)
                setInstalledProductIds.remove(instProd.Id);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: your first sentence should read: `Queueable Apex can make callouts when invoked by a batchable`