# When is Database.RaisesPlatformEvents needed on a Database.Batchable?

Tags: apex, batch, platform-event

This [Firing Platform Events from Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_platformevents.htm) documentation largely discusses automatically publishing a `BatchApexErrorEvent` on an unhandled exception:

> If the start, execute, or finish method of a batch Apex job encounters
> an unhandled exception, a BatchApexErrorEvent platform event is fired.
> For more details, see BatchApexErrorEvent.

if the class implements `Database.RaisesPlatformEvents`. So at first sight, this is a switch to turn on the automatic conversion of exceptions to the `BatchApexErrorEvent` Platform Event in Batchables to improve the error reporting.

My question is whether this interface also needs to be implemented to allow other Platform Events to be explicitly published via an `EventBus.publish` call? This is a different scenario not discussed in the linked documentation.

(A precedent here is that to make callouts you must implement `Database.AllowsCallouts`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no restriction preventing `EventBus.publish` from a `Database.Batchable`. **You can publish platform events without implementing `Database.RaisePlatformEvents`.** The only effect of this interface is that it automatically publishes `BatchApexErrorEvent` records in the case of an unhanded exception.

Comment: This post is based on previous experience, just checking with the latest API Versions to confirm.

Comment: Makes sense as the two cases have differing purposes. Do you know if you lose anything e.g. Apex Jobs logging by turning this on?

Comment: The jobs still get logged normally. I haven't found any loss based on implementing this interface.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Do you know if REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG qualifies for BatchApexErrorEvent?

Comment: I don't know, no.

Answer (score 0):

It's a switch to turn it on. You could try it by throwing your own exception in a batch class.

Comment: Thanks Theodoor. My batchable calls some existing code that does its own `EventBus.publish`. So I'm looking for confirmation that `Database.RaisesPlatformEvents` is required for that case as well as the automatic unhandled exception case.

Comment: As Adrian stated, it's not needed to publish your own events. It's just a switch to automatically get the events when it fails.