# Server-Side REST Authentication

Tags: oauth, rest

We are trying to interface with our SalesForce instance via HTTP. The idea would be to call some of our custom classes from outside salesforce but without any user interaction. Typical scenario is when our ERP System calls out to SalesForce to inform it about a new customer or order.

The plan is for our ERP to call something like `GET https://<our.salesforce.com>/our/res/class?param1=A&param2=B` (or POST with DATA).

I am reasonably well versed in making the actual REST classes but stumped when it comes to OAuth authentication. I take it Basic Authentication by encoding the `username:password` as `Authorization: Basic blahblah==` is out? So how to authenticate or get a Session ID?

Note, this is machine-to-machine communication with no user interaction. Yet the Remote Application setup in SalesForce requires me to enter a "Callback URL" which is described as "typically the URL that a user’s browser is redirected to after successful authentication". So what is atypical? What must I enter here?

### UPDATE

Here the CURL command I am using:

```
curl --form client_id=*****
     --form client_secret=*****
     --form grant_type=password
     --form username=blah%40blah.com.sandbox
     --form password=passwordTOKEN
     -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
```

Request:

```
POST https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
Host: test.salesforce.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 723
Expect: 100-continue
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; boundary=----------------------------e3e12e44c894

------------------------------e3e12e44c894
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_id"

*****
------------------------------e3e12e44c894
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_secret"

*****
------------------------------e3e12e44c894
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="grant_type"

password
------------------------------e3e12e44c894
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

blah%40blah.com.dev1
------------------------------e3e12e44c894
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

passwordTOKEN
------------------------------e3e12e44c894--
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Tue, 28 Jan 2014 13:20:53 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 81

{"error_description":"grant type not supported","error":"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

Tried using `test.salesforce.com` and `instance.salesforce.com` (which the docs use). Also tried with and without API token appended to password.

My client_id is 85 characters long.

Comment: Can your ERP append HTTP headers to the outgoing requests?

Comment: Sure, of course.

Comment: Needless to say `unsupported_grant_type` is *not* one of the documented error codes! https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm

Comment: you have to use login.salesforce if are using production or test.salesforce if are using a sandbox.  That error is typical when you are missing a header or have a wrong encoded value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890467/how-can-i-use-the-grant-type-password-oauth-flow-with-salesforce-com

Comment: I'm using `test.salesforce.com` as I'm in a sandbox. I've also 100% verified my credentials (username, password and token) into the same instance by using the SOAP API (https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/24.0)

Comment: I can now confirm that it does not matter whether the host is test.salesforce.com or our instance cs8.salesforce.com. Both work (or not as the case may be).

Comment: If your intent is to get an access token, you do **NOT** need to use OAuth. You can use the Soap based mechanism to get the access token and use that token in your REST calls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You must use OAth login flow first to have REST access**. There is a lot of good information out there about Salesforce OAuth login flow.

In order to make it programatically (Server to Server ), I think that the **most efficient way** is:

### Steps

1. Set the current **access_token** to the request header you need to do.
2. Make the request trying to **catch any exception**.
3. If you have an exception of type `401 Unauthorized` you have to launch the login flow and save the access_token for future requests.

Using this you don't have to go through the login flow on each request.

### Login

This is a sample of how to get the access_token:

**Request**

Realize an **HTTP POST**  to `https://[login].salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token`   **you must select between test or login according the environment we want to use (sandbox or production).

**Body**:

```
client_id=CLIENT-ID
&client_secret=CLIENTE-SECRET
&password=PASSWORD+SECURITY-TOKEN
&username=USERNAME
&grant_type=password
```

** replace default values with values from your org/user
**Headers**:

```
content-tpe: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Answer = Ok. Ex:

```
{
"id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/XXXX/XXXX",
"issued_at":"1378371927512",
"instance_url":"https://eu2.salesforce.com",
"signature":"XXXXXXX=",
"access_token":"_Z_ZZZZZZZZZZ"
}
```

Answer = Error Ex:

```
{
"error":"invalid_grant",
"error_description":"authentication failure - Invalid Password"
}
```

**WS Usage**

Once obtained the access_token and instance_url, you can send the requests to the web services

More [information](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en_US)

You will found a deeper information [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_OAuth_to_Authorize_External_Applications) about external applications on REST

Comment: I've tried your proposal (see my 'Answer' update) but get only 400 errors. The question remains: in order to setup OAuth I must enter a "Callback URL". What is that?

Comment: You must add the TOKEN and also check the header content-type. Set the callback using http://localhost/, that is used in other flows.

Comment: I've tried the password with and without the token. Also with and without the content-type header. Also using a vairety of callback URLs. Always get `grant type not supported`. btw. Typo: content-tpe

Comment: Your answer is correct in theory just doesn't work for me in practice. If I do exactly the same HTTP call from APEX code it works perfectly. I've tried whitelisting my IP (CURL client) to no avail.

Comment: Your question has changed. You first ask about what authentication you should implement, now you are asking about an error you are getting. Probably, the better way the community can help you is if you create a new question about the error.

Comment: I know but that's the way the problem developed. I've granted you had the correct answer, my troubles were a distraction difficult to document here satisfactorily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Username-Password OAuth Authentication Flow. The username-password authentication flow can be used to authenticate when the consumer already has the user’s credentials.
In this flow, the user’s credentials are used by the application to request an access token as shown in the following steps.

[image]

An example request body might look something like the following:

```
grant_type=password&client_id=3MVG9lKcPoNINVBIPJjdw1J9LLM82Hn
FVVX19KY1uA5mu0QqEWhqKpoW3svG3XHrXDiCQjK1mdgAvhCscA9GE&client_secret=
1955279925675241571&username=testuser%40salesforce.com&password=mypassword123456
```

Comment: So I need to use OAuth? Which means I need to enter a callback URL (or I can't enable OAuth)? See also my update (400 Error).

Comment: You can use any callback url when using this flow with OAuth

Comment: There's some info on http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22704/sessionid-problem-in-schedule-batch-class/23206#23206 answer that might help

Comment: Phil, that seems to deal with *remote* sites as in sites that my SF instance wants to call out to.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working (i.e. solved the enigmatic `unsupported_grant_type` error) though the reason remains unclear. It seems (my version of) CURL creates a different kind of request to "normal" HTTP clients which the REST endpoint is not understanding.

When I compared the POST with what apex `HttpRequest()` was doing I noticed CURL adds this header:

```
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; boundary=----...etc.
```

and then have a complex body using that boundary whilst other clients do without it:

content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

and have a simple body:

```
grant_type=password&client_id=....
```

Thanks a lot CURL, think I'll stick to Fiddler from now on.

So HTTP Request:

```
POST /services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: test.salesforce.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 241
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&client_id=***.***.***&client_secret=***&username=blah%40blah.com.dev1&password=blahTOKEN
```

Get's you:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

etc.

Comment: your problem was that you were using `--form` option to your parameters, they specify ` --form CONTENT  Specify HTTP multipart POST data (H)`, so curl actually created added body parts which probably doesn't make sense, as content type is not `multipart`, and so it added `boundary` to header. In order to make it work in curl, you need to use `-d` instead of `--form`