# Access rest service oauth

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, apexrest

I've looked at this question

[Server-Side REST Authentication](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25241/server-side-rest-authentication)

and many other forums with this same problem.  I'm trying to access restful webservice we created in our salesforce instance with postman.  I'm using this url
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
and these url params

```
grant_type=password
client_id={my id}
client_secret={my secret}
username=username@domain.com
password={password}{security token}
```

I'm getting this response

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "authentication failure"
}
```

In the connected app settings, I've added my IP under trusted IPs.  I've set IP Relaxation to "Relax IP restrictions".  I set permitted users to "All users may self-authorize".  I added my IP address under Administer->Security Controls->Network Access. 
Is there supposed to be a delimiter between password and security token in the password URL parameter?  I can view my connected app through two views in salesforce.

When I go to **Administer**->**Manage Apps**->**Connected Apps** I see it there but when I hover the mouse over it, it doesn't say "Managed-Installed" and it doesn't have the little blue arrow next to the link.  But when I click on it it says its installed

I also can view it through **Develop**->**Remote Access** which then redirects me to a page where I'm able to click on it and see the consumer key and consumer secret.

I tried sending a request from the developer console and I get the same error.  I tried sending with and without the security token appended to the password.  I do have the '@' character in the password, could that be causing a problem?

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
req.setBody('grant_type=password' + 
           '&client_id=' + 'id'+
           '&client_secret=' + 'secret' +
           '&username=' + 'username@domain.com.currentdev' +
           '&password=' + 'password');
Http h = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = h.send(req);
System.debug('Body ' + res.getBody());
System.debug('Status ' + res.getStatus());
System.debug('Status code ' + res.getStatusCode());
```

Thanks @Eric, the problem was I'm in a test environment so I should be using test.salesforce.com not login.salesforce.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the login history for the user and make sure you are connecting to the right url **TEST** vs **LOGIN**.

I am willing to bet that the **Security Token** is being required and you are not appending that to your password

You should be doing: `&password={PASSWORD}{SECURITYTOKEN}`

[image: Login History Example]

I used your code and once I added the IP to the allowed ranges (or appended the security token) it was successful.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
req.setBody('grant_type=password' + '&client_id=xyz' + '&client_secret=xyz' + '&username=un' + '&password=pw');
Http h = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = h.send(req);
System.debug('Body ' + res.getBody());
System.debug('Status ' + res.getStatus());
System.debug('Status code ' + res.getStatusCode());
```

results in:

> 15:00:19.37 (660162883)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|Body {"access_token":"xyz","instance_url":"https://xxx.my.salesforce.com","id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/xx/xx","token_type":"Bearer","issued_at":"1493838019636","signature":"xx"}
>
> 15:00:19.37 (660248503)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Status OK 15:00:19.37
>
> (660399942)|USER_DEBUG|[10]|DEBUG|Status code 200

[Digging Deeper into OAuth 2.0 on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Obtaining_an_Access_Token_in_a_Web_Application_.28Web_Server_Flow.29)

> An autonomous client can obtain an access token by simply providing
>   username, password and (depending on configuration) security token in
>   an access token request. Again the request is POSTed (1) to
>   **https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token**, but the payload
>   now has the form
>
> **grant_type=password&client_id=&client_secret=&username=&password=**
>
> The following parameters are required:
>
> - grant_type Set this to password.
> - client_id Your application's client identifier.
> - client_secret Your application's client secret. username The API user's Salesforce.com
> - username, of the form user@example.com.
> - password The API user's Salesforce.com password. If the client's IP address has not been whitelisted in your org, you must concatenate the
>     security token with the password.

Comment: I'm not seeing any login attempts in the login history when I run my code or send the request from postman

Comment: I'm positive.  I logged in, checked the login history and saw myself logging in from a browser.  Then clicked my name on the top menu, opened developer console, and executed that code.  I got a 400 bad request with that invalid_grant error and there was nothing in the login history

Comment: @gary69 - try adding `req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');` although for me it worked without it. What is the error description it is giving you? Do you have IP restrictions enabled? Is your username a production username? if not you need to change to test.salesforce.com.

Comment: When I set the header I get this error
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}
When I don't set the header I get this error
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"authentication failure"}

Comment: @gary69 Your username `username@domain.com.currentdev` makes it seem like you should be connecting to `test.salesforce.com` as it looks like a sandbox username

Comment: Yes!! Thank you, I needed test.salesforce instead of login.salesforce

Comment: Just accepted, I was just waiting because I thought you might make another answer with the solution of me using the wrong url.  Thank you so much for your help