# {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}

Tags: apex, callout, oauth2

I am getting the below error when trying to call the `HTTP POST` using the Apex

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
request.setMethod('POST');

request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.setHeader('client_id','3MVG9d8..z.hDcPJZPXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
request.setHeader('client_secret','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
request.setHeader('username','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
request.setHeader('password','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
request.setHeader('grant_type','password');
request.setHeader('callbackURL','https://ap5.salesforce.com/oauthcallback.html');

request.setBody('');

HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
System.debug('Response :: '+response.getBody());
```

And I get the error message.

```
Response :: {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}
```

I am able to call successfully using REST/POSTMAN client and getting the access_token.

Comment: Just a note, the `[apexrest]` tag is for when you are writing an `ApexClass` that will serve as a `@RestResource`, which does not appear to be the case here.

Comment: See answer here for troubleshooting: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172800/access-rest-service-oauth/172813?noredirect=1#comment260579_172813 - Also you do not need to provide the callback URL for the UN PW flow

Comment: @user4567570 Since you seem to be new here, just wanted to point out that it is considered being a good citizen to accept an answer if it solve your issue. You are under no obligation to do so but it helps others find answer to similar questions and also shows your appreciation to to efforts towards the person who spent time providing you with the answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change:

```
request.setEndpoint('https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
```

to either **Login** or **test** depending on if in production or sandbox

```
request.setEndpoint('https://[login | test].salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
```

You also need to put the parameters in the body or as URL params and not header

```
request.setBody(
      'grant_type=password' + 
      '&client_id=xxxx' + 
      '&client_secret=xx' + 
      '&username=xx' + 
      '&password=xx'
);
```

Comment: This worked for me today, in 2024. I had a Connected App setup the exact same way as my developer-edition org, and had everything else right, but was still getting this error. I was using the "my-domain" url, changed it to "test.salesforce.com" instead and bingo! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I understood the concept now and thanks for sharing other links.

`client_id, client_secret, username, password and grant_type` should be sent in a `HTTP POST` **body not in header.**

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.setEndpoint('https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');

String CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
String CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
String USERNAME = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
String PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

req.setBody('grant_type=password' + '&client_id='+CLIENT_ID + 
            '&client_secret='+CLIENT_SECRET + '&username='+USERNAME + '&password='+PASSWORD);

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse response = http.send(req);
System.debug('Body ' + response.getBody());
System.debug('Status ' + response.getStatus());
System.debug('Status code ' + response.getStatusCode());
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: Not really considered being a good citizen to post your own answer and accept it after accepting another answer when it does not offer any additional information than existing answers......

Answer (score 3):

Had the same error (SalesForce 2020). Under **Manage Connected Apps**, I had to make sure my selected OAuth Scopes were as follows

- Access and manage your data (api)
- Provide access to your data via the Web (web)
- Allow access to your unique identifier (openid)

For the server, I had to make sure I was using my **own** domain which you can follow under

```
Setup / My Domain / Your Domain Name
```

NodeJS

```
const jsforce = require('jsforce');
const conn = new jsforce.Connection({
    loginUrl: 'https://......salesforce.com',
});

const username = '.....';
const password = 'user_password' + 'user_security_token';
conn.login(username, password, function (err, userInfo) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); } else {
        console.log('connected');
    }
});
```

Note that password **is** a concatenation of the user's password and the user's Security Token.

Answer (score -2):

Also I found this as the simplest way.

```
Map<String, String> request = new Map<String, String>();
request.put('client_id','XXXXXXXXXXXX');
request.put('client_secret','XX');
request.put('username','XXX');
request.put('password','VXXXX');
request.put('grant_type','password');

String mapString = String.valueOf(request).replace(',','&')
    .replace(' ','').replace('{','').replace('}','');
System.debug('Request String '+mapString);

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.setEndpoint('https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
req.setBody(mapString);

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug('Body ' + res.getBody());
System.debug('Status ' + res.getStatus());
System.debug('Status code ' + res.getStatusCode());
```