# need to trigger email when data storage is hitting the limit

Tags: apex, trigger, data, configuration

i need to trigger email when data storage is hitting the limit.i dont see any configuration where i can set the email based on some usage.Please suggest.Is there any way without using the third party(appexchange)tools.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can use trigger here. But you can use scheduler class and Limit API to get these details.

Essentially, you have to build an apex class which does a callout to the REST API. You can then schedule that class to run in scheduled Apex. The big problem is that you have to pass a username and password as part of the login call to get a session:

1. [How to login and get a session](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22704/sessionid-problem-in-schedule-batch-class) -
2. Class to call the login:

```
public class CurrentStorage {

@Future(callout=true)
public static void getStorage() {

String sid = Login.login('', '');


HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint('
https://na2.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/limits');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+ sid);

Http http = new Http();

HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

Map m = (Map)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
Map dataStorage = (Map)m.get('DataStorageMB');

System.debug('Current Storage: ' + dataStorage.get('Remaining'));
return;
}

}
```

**Reference:**

- [Access Storage Used information through API](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006zM9AAI)
- [List Organization Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_limits.htm)