# Code Coverage for inner class having web service in salesforce

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have created the question - Scheduled reports and saving as salesforce documents

[Scheduled reports and saving as salesforce documents](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11948/scheduled-reports-and-saving-as-salesforce-documents)

I have put the whole class in an inner class, for which, the outer class is a batch class. I am having an issue with code coverage. I am not able to set the 'mockOutput' value which is in the inner class, from the test class.

I am expecting something like:

OuterClass outerObj = new OuterClass();
outerObj.InnerClass innerObj= new outerObj.InnerClass();
innerObj.innerVariable = xyz;

If I try the above, it says 'Invalid Type outerObj.InnerClass'

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

It would be `OuterClass.InnerClass`, not `outerObj.InnerClass`. Classes are, by definition, `static`, as only one instance of the class exists in the system. Note that if the inner class is private, you may need to use `@TestVisible` in order to gain access to it from the test method.