# Apex not saving Dashboard Image

Tags: apex, httprequest, image-formula

I have tried this codes but the image is still not being save into the file in the `Document Folder`.

Can anyone help me fix my code so that it can save an image?

---

Apex Class

```
public void send(){

    String image1 = 'https://ap4.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ChartServer?rsid=0FL6F000002dBX3&ruid=0056F00000746E0&did=01Z6F000001DwLb&s=7&fs=10&tfg=12&tfs=-16772063&explode=0&c=gauge&cs=0&title=Closed+Sales+To+Date&eh=no&compo=no&fg=-16777216&bg1=-1&bg2=-1355393&bgdir=2&dl1=Account+Name&dl2=&l=2&sax=yes&Yman=no&nc=0&actUrl=%2F00O2F00000Aug7k%3Fdbw%3D1&sd=1&scv=no&sct=yes&spt=no&bd=yes&cu=SGD&ab=X&u=0&vt=0&ab2=Y&u2=1&vt2=2&vl0=Sum+of+Amount&spoc=no&topn=no&gm=0.0&gc0=-6750208&gm0=500000.0&gc1=-13210&gm1=1000000.0&gc2=-16738328&gm2=1500000.0&sona=0&refreshts=1491552381000';


    String base64Data = '';
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(image1);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    Blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();
    base64Data =  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image);
    System.debug('image= ' + image);

    Document docatt = new Document();
    docatt.Name = 'Chart 1.jpg';
    docatt.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
    docatt.FOLDERID = '00l6F231005tqGi';
    docatt.IsPublic = true;

    insert docatt;

}
```

---

Image file that was saved:

[image: Saved Image File]

Comment: Assuming the `image1` URL you have works fine from a browser session then the problem will be a missing cookie with a Salesforce Session ID to authenticate the request. You will need to set the `sid` cookie to a valid Session ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set a valid `sid` cookie on the request to authenticate it.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
//...
req.setHeader('Cookie', 'sid=' + UserInfo.getSessionId()+ ';');
//...
```

Also consider the HttpResponse to see what went wrong. E.g.

```
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug('Status Code: ' + res.getStatusCode());
```

Comment: just wondering if there way? It's because I want to put his into a scheduler to insert the image into the Document Folder and I might not be online at that point of time that it upload the image file

Comment: Establishing a session from a scheduled job is a whole other problem. Have a search, as there are other questions that have addressed that issue.

Comment: [Session ID from scheduled jobs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/9261/102)

Comment: The last time I tried putting 2 HTTP method in the same class I had an error. The [other method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221170/retrieve-salesforce-daily-api-requests-limit) that was given I don't understand the codes to implement it into the scheduler.