# Modifying HTTP Call for Scheduler to Upload Dashboard Images

Tags: apex, httprequest, httppost

I have created the HTTP method using this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/session-id-from-scheduled-jobs). But I'm unsure of how to test it out. Say if I run this in the Developer Console for testing how Can I link it to taking the image out of the Salesforce Dashboard and uploading it into the Document Folder so that the Image can be send upload else where?

> I already have the URL to those Dashboard images that I want to upload

***How do I link this to getting a image from Salesforce Dashboard and uploading it into the Document Folder?***

---

**Codes**

```
public class testFBInt {

public void exInt() {

  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(buildHttpQuery(new Map<String, String> {
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 'Consumer_id',
        'client_secret' => 'Consumer_key'
         }));

 }

  static String buildHttpQuery(Map<String, String> queryParams) {
    if (queryParams.isEmpty()) {
        return '';
    }

    String[] params = new String[] {};
    for (String k : queryParams.keySet()) {
        String v = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(queryParams.get(k), 'UTF-8');

        params.add(String.format('{0}={1}', new String[] { k, v }));
    }

    return String.join(params, '&');
 }

}
```

Comment: Why are you making a callout to upload it to Document? Is it in different org?

Comment: I need to upload the image file that is from the Dashboard and then send the image file to Facebook that is why I'm trying to upload it as a Document
unless here is another way to send a specific image of the graph from the Dashboard to Facebook?

Comment: There is 2 things here: 1. To save the image as Document, you dont need callout for this. 2. Sending the image to facebook, it needs a callout. Your question doesn't talk about callout to facebook.

Comment: But i need a call out for it in the scheduler don't I?

Comment: **If its in the same org**, you can insert document record without a callout even from a scheduler. But to send the image to facebook, you need a callout.

Comment: The reason why i need a scheduler is because I need the image to be save and send over to facebook at a certain time. If not i will just use a codes from my previous post and then send over to facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your statement

> I already have the URL to those Dashboard images that I want to upload

From here, there are 3 task you talked about. All these can be done in a scheduler job.

**One:** Fetching the image body as base64data.

Get the access token first. Reference: [Alan's answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/session-id-from-scheduled-jobs)

Lets say your URL is in variable - `dashboardImageURL`.

```
String base64Data;
httprequest req = new httprequest();
req.setEndpoint(dashboardImageURL);
req.setmethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + access_token);
http http = new http();
httpresponse res = http.send(req);
Blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();
base64Data =  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image);
```

**Two:** Saving the image as Document in current org.

```
Document docatt = new Document();
docatt.Name = 'Chart 1.jpg';
docatt.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
docatt.FOLDERID = '00l6F231005tqGi'; //Your folder id
docatt.IsPublic = true;

insert docatt;
```

You can have a scheduler job to run at any specific time with these 2 snippets to save the image from the URL.

**Three:** Sending the image to Facebook.

For this you will need to make another callout to facebook with the image body set in the `httprequest` body. This is not a part of the question, so I am just over-lining it. You can write it in a separate scheduler if you want to send it at a different time or in the same scheduler job.

Comment: But where do I get that `Session Id` from my code in the post? For the scheduler

Comment: That's a good point. For that you have the code with you in your question. Get the access token using that and then continue. I have updated my answer.